# Удаление из вектора

Tags: c++

Есть `int` вектор, элементы с чётными индексами которого содержат координаты x "близлежащих" точек, а нечётные - координаты y таких же точек. Соседние координаты отличаются либо на 0, либо на 1, т.е. соседними точками точки (0,3),(1,3) могут быть, а (1,2),(3,2) - нет (---- см. пример*).

**Пример**: `1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1` - вектор с точками `(1,1),(1,2),(2,2),(2,1)`, причём координаты x и y последующих точек отличаются от предыдущих на 0 или 1; полученная фигура - квадрат; он мог быть задан либо `11122221`, либо `12222111` - главное, чтобы точки шли по порядку без повторов.

Так вот, если у нас задан, например, вектор `1,1,2,2,3,3,4,2,5,1,4,1,3,1,2,1`, т.е. треугольник по точкам (`1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,2),(5,1),(4,1),(3,1),(2,1)` с вершинами  `(1,1),(3,3),(5,1)`, то хотелось бы из изначального вектора получить вектор с этими 3 вершинами, т.е. `1,1,3,3,5,1` , т.е. **удалить промежуточные точки**, которые "не играют роли" из вектора (для любой фигуры, а не только треугольника).

Вот мой код по удалению этих точек:

```
i=0; // текущий индекс 
while (i<v.size()-1) // до последней координаты x
{
    int prevX=(!i ? v[v.size()-2] : v[i-2]),nextX=(i==v.size()-2 ? v[0] : v[i+2]),prevY=(!i ? v[v.size()-1] : v[i-1]),nextY=(i==v.size()-2 ? v[1] : v[i+3]); // получаем предыдущие и следующие координаты
    if (v[i]==(prevX+nextX)/2 && v[i+1]==(prevY+nextY)/2){ // если условие удаления выполняется
        v.erase(v.begin()+i,v.begin()+i+2); // вот здесь не уверен, пробовал два удаления подряд - безрезультатно
        vector<int>(v).swap(v); // очистка памяти
    } else i+=2; // продвигаем индекс на следующую координату x (при удалении индекс сам "продвигается")
}
```

Суть в том, что проверяется, является ли координата x текущей точки (в векторе `v[i]`) средним арифметическим для предыдущей `v[i-2]` и последующей `v[i+2]` координат x. Аналогично для y.

Он не работает, подозреваю, что ошибка в самом удалении. Прошу указать на ошибку/и.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32618/discussion-on-question-by-viktor---).

Answer (score 1):

Уберите деление из условий, запишите 2*v[i]==...